# LOAD DATA INFILE syntax error

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

query: `load data infile 'systemmessage.txt' ignore into table systemmessage (message) lines starting by 'a,' terminated by '\0' ignore 1 lines`

gives me a syntax error near 'lines starting by'.
If I remove the 'starting by' part, the error is now with 'terminated by'. If I remove that too, the error is with 'ignore 1 lines'.
Where the hell is the problem?? The file exists, the table exists, if I remove all checks it loads, but with the wrong data.

Comment: prepare again your systemmessage.txt to be exactly follow mysql specification - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: OMG the problem is not in systemmessage.txt! It's an SQL syntax error! I'm ready to blow up with this incredibly dumb problem and you suggest me something I've been reading hundreds of times in the past few hours! Anyway, I finally managed to get past this but wasted more nerves than in the past week together...

Comment: you should just fool proof your systemmessage.txt is 100% compliance with mysql specification, did you try just insert a single line (single record) to ensure at least it will work for 1 line ?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to move the column list to the end of the SQL statement.

As described in the manual, the format info (lines starting by, skip 1 lines, etc) need to be specified before the (optional) column list:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Here's the fixed query:

```
load data infile '/tmp/systemmessage.txt' 
ignore into table systemmessage 
lines starting by 'a,' 
terminated by '\0' 
ignore 1 lines
(message)
```